# how do I perform segue after log in with facebook account?

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase, segue

Currently I am attempting to perform a segue to a second view controller after a user logs in with Facebook using firebase

I was able to sort of get this to work. My problem is I have to actually log-in twice before the Segue is activated. Any suggestions?

see my CODE below

```
private var fbLoginSuccess = false //This is gobal

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil && fbLoginSuccess == true)
{

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Home", sender: self)

}
 }

@IBAction func facebookLogin(sender: UIButton) {

let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"],        from: self, handler: {
    (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
    if facebookError != nil {
        print("Facebook login failed. Error \(String(describing: facebookError))")
    } else if (facebookResult?.isCancelled)! {
        print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
    } else {


        let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Login failed. \(String(describing: error))")
            } else {
                 fbLoginSuccess = true
                print("Logged in!")

                if (facebookResult?.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))! {

                }
            }
            }
    }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're only calling `performSegue(withIdentifier:)` in `viewDidAppear`. If you want the segue to occur after signing in, then you need to include it there.

```
let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self, handler: {
    (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
    if facebookError != nil {
        print("Facebook login failed. Error \(String(describing: facebookError))")
    } else if (facebookResult?.isCancelled)! {
        print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
    } else {
        let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Login failed. \(String(describing: error))")
            } else {
                 fbLoginSuccess = true
                print("Logged in!")

                if (facebookResult?.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))! {

                }
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "Home", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
})
```